# .NET 6 Code analyzer CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors breaking

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

We are trying to enable to .NET 6 Code Analyzer on our .NET 472 projects.
In most projects we have WarningsAsErrors set to true. We dont want to CA warnings to report as an error, so we added CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors as false.

When doing so, all the CA warnings are no longer reported

We now use the following settings

```
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningsNotAsErrors>$(WarningsNotAsErrors);CS8073;CS8882;CS8887;CS8848</WarningsNotAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Without the settings, we have 0 warnings. With these settings, only a few additional CS warnings are triggered, the ones we had to add in the WarningsNotAsErrors

If i remove the CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors property and set TreatWarningsAsErrors to false, i get 1700 CA warnings in our code base.
I would expect to see these 1700 warnings with above settings as well.
When i set CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors to true, i get 1700 errors.

I am using this in my global.json file

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "6.0.300",
        "rollForward": "latestFeature"
    }
}
```

and have sdk's 6.0.300 and 6.0.401 installed, along with VS 17.2

Why is CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors breaking our code analysis scan?
Any advice would be helpful.

Edit: adding images
[image]

[image]

VS shows it wants to treat them as warning:
[image]

Comment: updated to sdk 308 and 405, same result

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/codeanalysistreatwarningsaserrors-false-still-trea/1425763

Comment: Hi Dou, I am still facing this issue. I dont understand how its supposed to work. As soon as i include CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors in my csproj, the warnings are only reported when i have the code file open (as per the vs configuration appearently), but without CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors  i do get errors without the code file open, why is that?
Also, i expect to get the same warnings in MSBuild, where i cannot have the code file open. How do i ensure i always get the warnings through MSBuild.exe?

Comment: Hi, [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/configure-live-code-analysis-scope-managed-code?view=vs-2022#default-analysis-scope) has mentioned analysis scope that maybe gives some help. But how the analyzer works is a bit confusing and i'm looking for some MS docs.

Comment: When enabling the Analyszer with CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors set to false, the warnings also do not appear through a build with MSBuild. If i report them as errors they will. How can we get MSBuild to report these warnings as well?

Comment: In the default analysis mode (Default), only a small number of rules are enabled as build warnings. I guess the reason why the CA warnings don't appear through a MSBuild may be disabling some CA warnings such as CA 1051.Please refer to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview?tabs=net-6#enable-additional-rules).

Comment: I am setting the Analysis mode to Recommended, so i would expect them during my MSBuild build as well

Comment: I compare `Build only` and `Build + IntelliSense` in  Error List. I found different warnings are displayed with two modes above. See [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD2Sn.png) and [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Ngt.png).But as  far as the document i am looking at, i'm afraid you couldn't expect them with MSBuild CLI as well .

Comment: Oke, so the warnings are only supposed to show up in Visual Studio, unless report as error is enabled, then they do show up in MSBuild.
Still sounds a bit weird to me though.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, I mean warnings not only show up in Visual Studio but also in MSBuild. The difference is `Build only` and `Build + IntelliSense` in VS. I tested with MSBuild like this `msbuild test.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:WarningLevel=7` and some CA warnigns are show(e.g CA1418) and some are not(e.g CA1051).Please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjuYB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I set  `TreatWarningsAsErrors` and  `CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors` to `true` or `false` for Combinatorial testing. Below are several test results.

scenario 1

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

This returns all CS errors.

scenario 2

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>false </TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

This returns all CS warnings.

scenario 3

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
<EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
<AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
```

scenario 4

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
<EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
<AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
<CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

Both 3 and 4 returns CS and CA errors.
[image]

scenario 5

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
<EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
<AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
<CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false </CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

This returns CS errors and CA warnings.
[image]

scenario 6

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>false </TreatWarningsAsErrors>
<EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
<AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
<CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors> (Or it can be removed)
```

This returns  CA and CS warnings.
[image]

From your description,

> I would expect to see these 1700 warnings with above settings as well.

My understanding is that if you want to see warnings, you can follow scenario 6. I’m afraid you can’t see these 1700 warnings with above settings as well.

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors> <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>)
```

But I'm not sure exactly what your question is from your last paragraph.
If there is any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

**UPDATE1/30/2023**

If scenario 5 doesn't work in your machine, i suggest you check below setting 1 and setting 2 or try method 3.

1 Custom analysis scope

By default, compiler diagnostics run on all open documents, and, in Visual Studio 2022 and later, Roslyn analyzer diagnostics run on the currently active document only.You can custom analysis scope.For example:
[image]

2 set warning levels
[image]

3 Run code analysis manually
Error list will soon refresh with all code analysis diagnostics.Please refer to  doc: [Run code analysis manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-run-code-analysis-manually-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022#run-code-analysis-manually)

**UPDATE 2/2/2013**

Steps below  are my process of creating demo project and getting the warnings. You can follow those steps and see if warnings are show.

1 create C# console app project named `CodeAnalyzeTest`.

2 copy code below to `Program.cs` and install package Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CodeAnalyzeTest
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Account account = new Account
            {
                Name = "John Doe",
                Email = "john@nuget.org",
                DOB = new DateTime(1980, 12, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }
}
```

3 edit project file and add PropertyGroup

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
        <AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors> 
<CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

4 build the project and watch error list.You'll get CA and CS warnings.
[image]

If you still get no warnings after following steps above, please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.

What i want is scenario 5. But on my machine, this is not working, as soon as i add CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors, or WarningsNotAsErrors with the specific id, the CA warnings disapear completely.

Comment: Hi, i've updated my answer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for that, changing the Visual Studio setting to scan on the entire solution brings back the warning (and more), but when building through msbuild.exe i still get no warnings.
It is my expectation that anyone who builds this solution/project, will see the warning as per the project configuration. When removing CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors they appear as error, so the analysis runs, how can i make sure using csproj settings they are always reported to the UI and MSBuild?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to your project. You can recreate a demo project and configure as scenario 5 and see if warnings are show.

Comment: Yes i can reproduce the problem in a sample solution, above screenshots are made in this sample

Comment: Hi, i provide a simple demo code and you can follow steps above and see if it works in your side or provide a minimal ,reproducible example.

Comment: The code in my screenshot is my full code, its just a new solution with that csproj, generate a random CA warning in your class and thats all i have